# The song played on Boku no Hero Academia in episode 55 (S3E17) about Todoroki vs Ninjas fight part 2

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

There's a song fairly at the beginning of episode 55 (season 3 episode 17) of *Boku no Hero Academia* when Todoroki fights with ninjas.

When searching for the answer, all I can get is the song that plays in the episode BEFORE this, but this one is different.

What is this song?

Answer (score 0):

I found it randomly when it switched to scene from AfO fight
its:
The Power of Endeavor
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=887nqfBTRaw